# Elastic Search query Not workng with java but with elastic URI

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I created an Index for a few documents. However I am facing trouble while running for a search query as it is showing zero hits. Find the indexing file, indexed data and and Java code below:

`Mapping.json`:

```html
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 39
    },
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "custom_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "custom_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 40,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "whitespace",
            "punctuation",
            "symbol"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "type_name": {  
      "properties": {
      "primaryTerm": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
        "fielddata": "true",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "custom_normalizer"
          }
        }
      },
      "entityType": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "custom_normalizer"
      },
      "variants": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
        "fielddata": "true",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "custom_normalizer"
          }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`Elastic data.json`:

```html
    {
  "took": 82,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "relmap",
        "_type": "type_name",
        "_id": "X4NutXcBKX-KYFzehi4s",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "entityType": "Agency",
          "primaryTerm": "K2IPR INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY ATTORNEYS",
          "variants": [
            "K2IPR",
            "K2I.P.R. (PATENT & TRADEMARK ATTRONEYS)",
            "K2I.P.R",
            "K2.I.P.R",
            "K2 I.P.R",
            "K2  I.P.R",
            "K2 IPR",
            "K2 I. P. R."
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "relmap",
        "_type": "type_name",
        "_id": "YINutXcBKX-KYFzeoy7V",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "entityType": "Agency",
          "primaryTerm": "EPIPHANY IP SOLUTIONS PVT. LTD.",
          "variants": [
            "EPIPHANY IP SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED",
            "EPIPHANY IP SOLUTIONS PVT. LTD"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "relmap",
        "_type": "type_name",
        "_id": "YYNutXcBKX-KYFzepC44",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "entityType": "Agency",
          "primaryTerm": "Natural Remedies Private Limited",
          "variants": [
            "NATURAL REMEDIES PVT. LTD",
            "NATURAL REMEDIES PVT LTD",
            "NATURAL REMEDIES"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "relmap",
        "_type": "type_name",
        "_id": "YoNutXcBKX-KYFzepC5i",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "entityType": "Agency",
          "primaryTerm": "NICHE, INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY OFFICES",
          "variants": [
            "NICHE INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY OFFICES",
            "NICHE INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY OFFICECS",
            "NICHE INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY LAW OFFICES"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Search query:

```html
  String query="{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\""+searchTerm.toUpperCase()+"\",\"default_operator\":\"AND\",\"default_field\":\"primaryTerm\"}}";
```

Java Code for elastic Query:

```html
SearchResponse searchResponse=null;
        try {
            String queryJson=json;
            System.out.println("queryJson:"+queryJson);
            //System.out.println(indexName);
            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexName); 
            SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
            
            searchSourceBuilder.from(start)
                                .size(length)
                                .query(QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(queryJson));
            
            searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
            
            
            searchResponse = elasticsearchRestTemplate.getClient().search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

For a Search Term = 'Ni' in an autosuggest drpDown I am getting zero hits for the field 'primaryTerm'

I also tried the `termQuerybuilder` instead of wrapper query:

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("relmap");
        
SearchResponse searchResponse = searchRequestBuilder.
                                     setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("variants", "NATURAL REMEDIES PVT. LTD"))).setFrom(0).setSize(1000).setExplain(true).setTrackTotalHits(true).execute().actionGet();
SearchHits searchHits = searchResponse.getHits();
```

Interestinlgy I am getting the desired output with elastic url.

Elastic URI code:

```
http://localhost:9201/relmap/_search?q=NIC&df=primaryTerm&explain=true&default_operator=AND
```

Can anyone help let me know the fault /correct way to get the hits from the query

Comment: Does it work for you if you do a simple "match all" request, like in the very first example in [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search-request)? I have just tried out your JSON query with your data, and it works for me. (Note: in the mapping you have `type_name` and not `relmap`. If the index name is wrong it can be a problem.)

Comment: Match All works fine .even changing the type_name is not helping...I need output to match the term query